# Grails - Disable automatic marshalling

Tags: xml, json, grails, marshalling

I'm using Grails 2.3.6.

I have generated my controllers and views using:

```
grails generate-all com.mypackage.mydomainclass
```

I would like to disable automatic JSON/XML marshalling for domain objects and implement only my own services.

I have tried adding the following to my controller:

```
static responseFormats = ['html']
```

And it seems to work, is it the proper way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.6/ref/Controllers/responseFormats.html), it looks like you are correct.  Athough, it looks like they generally use it to extend support for other types by adding more types, whereas you are using it to limit.